# read html file from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to read `html` file and load control in `ascx` file in asp.net.I search in net but unable to find any resource.Please suggest links or any solution.Thanks.

Comment: once off? or is this a HTML file that changes and you want to keep reading it on the fly?

Comment: Question is not so clear. Do you want to read an existing html file then load a custom control `ascx`? If you have some code, please try to show them here.

Comment: ya i want to read existing html file and write in ascx  and also include ContainPlaceHolder between every <div></div>.Its my requirement and i haven't any idea about this.

Comment: can you show the ascx? or at least where do you want to place the html? in a PlaceHolder ?

Comment: also do you know how to read the file?

Answer (score 0):

I use ASP to make HTML directly, if you have the HTML file, you may wish to save it as .aspx but use this line to call your ascx page:

```
<%@CodeFile="nameFile.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_features" %>
```

I always put this at the tippy top of the page. Hope this helps (and that i've got it right, because Visual Studio usually does it for me!)

Comment: But i have multipal html file which is generated by user and i want to choose one of them and write in ascx file as user choice and also include ContainPlaceHolder between every <div></div>.